# MDB transaction retry interval

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, message-driven-bean

Can we control the transaction retry interval in MDB? If so, please provide an example or direct me to the documentation. We want to set up a time interval of 3 min for MDB transactions. The desire is that if the query fails \first time, then it retries after 3 min of time has elapsed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vairam;

Take a look at the Hornet Documentation for [Message Redelivery](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.2.Final/user-manual/en/html/undelivered-messages.html). The issues you need to consider are:

- The redelivery delay (you indicated 3 minutes).
- The number of times the message should be redelivered.
- If you elect **not** to redeliver indefinitely, the final action that occurs when the last redelivery attempt fails which could be:

  - Drop the message.
  - Enqueue the message to the designated DLQ.
  - Enqueue the message to some other queue.

**Setting the redelivery delay**

Delayed redelivery is defined in the address-setting configuration.

Example:

```
 <!-- delay redelivery of messages for 3m -->
 <address-setting match="jms.queue.exampleQueue">
    <redelivery-delay>300000</redelivery-delay>
 </address-setting>
```

**Setting the maximum number of redeliveries and DLQ configuration**

This can be defined declaratively by specifying the DLQ configuration in the address-setting configuration:

Example:

```
 <!-- undelivered messages in exampleQueue will be sent to the dead letter address 
    deadLetterQueue after 3 unsuccessful delivery attempts
  -->
 <address-setting match="jms.queue.exampleQueue">
    <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.deadLetterQueue</dead-letter-address>
    <max-delivery-attempts>3</max-delivery-attempts>
 </address-setting>
```

If you want to drop the message after the designated number of redelivery failures, check the message header value of **"JMSXDeliveryCount"** and if that number is equal to the maximum redeliveries, simply supress any exceptions and commit the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your replay nicholas. we are using jms with hornetq.

Comment: hi,thanks a lot for your reply. Is there any API to view the number of messages in the queue. so that we view the messages in the queue.